# Show that the expression $Ť([v]) = Tv$ indeed defines a function $ Ť: V / \ker T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces on the same field and let $T: V \to W$  a surjective linear transformation
Show that the expression $Ť([v]) = Tv$ indeed defines a function $ Ť: V / \ker T$

I need help for this exercise, I have a hint that I think can solve the problem but I have not reached the solution

HINT: take another representative of the same equivalence class.
Thus, if $ u \in [v] $, the expression takes the same values, i.  e., $ Tu = Tv $

Comment: You're trying to prove that $Ť$ is a well defined function.  Are you comfortable with the concept of showing that a function on an equivalence class that is defined via representatives is in fact well defined?

Comment: It might help to look up the first isomorphism theorem, and the universal property of homomorphisms.

Comment: I'm not currently comfortable enough